# Dynamically Load class in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class `Test` which is in `lib` folder and I want to make an object of this class dynamically inside a method of my controller class name `class UsersController < ApplicationController`. How can I do this?

something like

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController  
  def address
    {"here I want to create the object of Test class"}
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean under "dynamically"? You want to instantiate it or what?

Comment: yes exactly I want to instantiate it but before that in my controller class there is no any reference of Test class(I do not include Test Class in UserController class). So at runtime I want to add the reference of Test class and also make the object of Test class and access the methods of Test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby you can't create object like in C++, you can create only dynamic object with `Object::new` method. So to create instance of `Test` class you simple wrote:

```
test = Test.new
```

Comment: but I want the object of test class at run time and before the compilation my controller class don't know about any reference of Test Class means I do not include Test class into controller class.

Comment: So what's the problem? If your test class is in `lib` then it will be automatically loaded when it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no compilition in ruby. And Test is just constant which   is available anywhere, if it was defined in main scope ofc.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is interpreted language so there is no compilation phase.in config/application.rb load lib folder or file so when boots it automatically load these file. now if you want instance of test class for all the method simply create method which create instance and load before method using `before_filter`